# Content repeat collecting problems while use filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Recently we will use filebeat to collect our system logs to elasticsearch vias:

```
${local_log_file} -> filebeat -> kafka -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana
```

While testing our system, we found a scenario that filebeat will repeatly collect logs which means that it will collect logs from the start of file once there is a change.

here is my configuration for filebeat:

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /home/XXX/exp/*.log

scan_frequency: 1s
#tail_files: true
#================================ Outputs =====================================
#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
# output.logstash:
#   hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

#----------------------------- Kafka output -----------------------------------
output.kafka:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["10.10.1.103:9092"]
  topic: egou

#----------------------------- console output --------------------------------
output.console:
  enabled: true
  pretty: true
```

Notice:

1. we construct the log files manually, and we are sure that there is a blank line at the end of file
2. to make a console, we open the output.console
3. once there is content appended to the end of log file, filebeat will collect from the beginning of the file.But we hope just fetching the change of file.
4. filebeat version is 5.6.X

Hope any useful hint can be offered by u all

Comment: It works well with real time log files collected from logback or tools based on slf4J

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the editor, you are using, creates a new file on save with new meta-data. Filebeat identifies the state of the file using its meta-data, not the content.

try,

```
echo "something" >> /path/to/file.log
```

ref: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-repeatedly-sending-old-entries-in-log-file/55796